# How to give parameter in rest client when calling moodle webservice function?

Tags: web-services, rest

**rest client.php**

```
<?php

$token = '4f920ddef0bd90d84ef316621fde6d22';

$domainname = 'localhost';

$functionname = 'local_wstemplate_hello_world';

$we='hello';

$restformat = 'json'; 

$params = array($we);

/// REST CALL
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$serverurl = $domainname . '/moodle/server/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname;

require_once('./curl.php');

$curl = new curl;

$restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';

$resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat ,$params);

print_r($resp);
```

I have a function which takes string as argument and then displays it.but i cant figure out how to give the parameter.it always throw this error

```
{"exception":"invalid_parameter_exception","errorcode":"invalidparameter","message":"Invalid parameter value detected","debuginfo":"Missing required key in single structure: welcomemessage"}
```

I am new to moodle.So anyone can tell me how to pass parameter to the function?

Answer (score -1):

It will most likely work when you make a complex object with all required information instead of a simple array. So try something like this:

```
/// SETUP - NEED TO BE CHANGED
$token =  '4f920ddef0bd90d84ef316621fde6d22';
$domainname = 'localhost';
$functionname = 'core_user_create_users';

// REST RETURNED VALUES FORMAT
$restformat = 'json';

/// PARAMETERS - NEED TO BE CHANGED IF YOU CALL A DIFFERENT FUNCTION
$user1 = new stdClass();
$user1->username = 'testusername10';
$user1->password = 'Testpassword1*';
// ...more properties omitted
$preferencename1 = 'preference1';
$preferencename2 = 'preference2';
$user1->preferences = array(
    array('type' => $preferencename1, 'value' => 'preferencevalue1'),
    array('type' => $preferencename2, 'value' => 'preferencevalue2'));

$users = array($user1);
$params = array('users' => $users);

/// REST CALL
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname;
require_once('./curl.php');

$curl = new curl;
//if rest format == 'xml', then we do not add the param for backward compatibility with Moodle < 2.2
$restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';
$resp = $curl->post($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
print_r($resp);
```